# Time and keypress events with Python's Turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am trying to create a simple game with turtle:

- A turtle controlled by the user can shoot bullets when `space` is pressed
- An enemy turtle is created at a random position
- If the enemy is hit by the bullet, the enemy is destroyed and moves to a new position.
- If the bullet leaves the screen, it disappears.
- While the bullet is moving, the player should still be able to move.
- If the enemy is not destroyed in 20 seconds, the player looses.

Therefore, I need some events to be controlled with the keyboard and others that get triggered after a certain time. I cannot think about a way of doing this without a loop inside which I check the distance between the bullet and the enemy, but if I do it like that, I cannot control the main turtle during the loop.

```
import turtle as trtl
from random import randint
import time

class Game():
    def __init__(self):
        self.scr = trtl.Screen()
        self.scr.update()

        self.player = trtl.Turtle()
        self.player.shape('turtle')
        self.player.penup()

        trtl.onkeypress(self.forward,'w')
        trtl.onkeypress(self.backwards,'s')
        trtl.onkeypress(self.left,'a')
        trtl.onkeypress(self.right,'d')
        trtl.onkeypress(self.shoot,'space')
        trtl.listen()

        self.enemy = trtl.Turtle()
        self.enemy.shape('square')
        self.enemy.penup()
        self.enemy.speed(0)
        self.move_enemy()

        self.bullet = trtl.Turtle()
        self.bullet.penup()
        self.bullet.hideturtle()
        self.bulletShot = False


    def forward(self):
        self.player.forward(5)

    def backwards(self):
        self.player.back(5)

    def left(self):
        self.player.left(6)

    def right(self):
        self.player.right(6)

    def shoot(self):
        if self.bulletShot == False:
            self.bullet.speed(0)
            self.bullet.goto(self.player.pos())
            self.bullet.seth(self.player.heading())
            self.bullet.showturtle()
            self.bulletShot = True

    def move_enemy(self):
        x = randint(-300,300)
        y = randint(-300,300)
        self.enemy.hideturtle()
        self.enemy.goto(x,y)
        self.enemy.showturtle()

    def play(self):
        startTime = time.time()
        print(time.time() - startTime)
        while time.time() - startTime < 20:
            if self.bulletShot:
                self.bullet.forward(1)
                collision = self.bullet.distance(self.enemy.pos()) < 10
                isIn = (self.bullet.pos()[0] <= 300 and 
                        self.bullet.pos()[0] >= -300 and 
                        self.bullet.pos()[1] <= 300 and 
                        self.bullet.pos()[1] >= -300)

                if not(isIn):
                    self.bullet.hideturtle()
                    self.bulletShot = False
                elif collision:
                    self.bullet.hideturtle()
                    self.bulletShot = False
                    self.move_enemy()
                    startTime = time.time()

        self.player.write('You loose')
        self.scr.exitonclick()


game = Game()
game.play()
```

I tried a simpler version in which one turtle moves automatically in a loop and another turtle is controlled with the keyboard, and it works well.

```
import turtle as trtl

def up():
    jane.sety(jane.pos()[1] + 10)

def down():
    jane.sety(jane.pos()[1] - 10)

scr = trtl.Screen()
scr.update()

bob = trtl.Turtle()
bob.penup()
bob.seth(180)
bob.setx(300)
bob.speed(1)

jane = trtl.Turtle()
jane.penup()

trtl.onkeypress(up,'w')
trtl.onkeypress(down,'s')
trtl.listen()

while True:
    if bob.pos()[0] > -300:
        bob.forward(10)
    else:
        break

scr.exitonclick()
```

Is there a way of fixing this with turtle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it without changing much the code and without making the function `play()` recursive. The problem was that if the `if` inside de `while` needs an `else`, otherwise, the key press is not recorded. So I gave it something to do and now it works as I want.

```
while time.time() - startTime < 20:
    if self.bulletShot:
        self.bullet.forward(3)
        ...
    else:
        self.scr.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's redesign the game to work *with* turtle's event system by using a timer event to control the action while still using your timer to limit play time:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randint
import time

class Game():
    def __init__(self):
        self.startTime = -1

        self.screen = Screen()
        self.screen.tracer(False)

        self.player = Turtle()
        self.player.shape('turtle')
        self.player.penup()

        self.enemy = Turtle()
        self.enemy.shape('square')
        self.enemy.penup()
        self.move_enemy()

        self.bullet = Turtle()
        self.bullet.hideturtle()
        self.bullet.penup()
        self.bulletShot = False

        self.screen.onkeypress(self.forward, 'w')
        self.screen.onkeypress(self.backwards, 's')
        self.screen.onkeypress(self.left, 'a')
        self.screen.onkeypress(self.right, 'd')
        self.screen.onkeypress(self.shoot, 'space')
        self.screen.listen()

    def forward(self):
        self.player.forward(5)
        self.screen.update()

    def backwards(self):
        self.player.back(5)
        self.screen.update()

    def left(self):
        self.player.left(6)
        self.screen.update()

    def right(self):
        self.player.right(6)
        self.screen.update()

    def shoot(self):
        if not self.bulletShot:
            self.bullet.setposition(self.player.position())
            self.bullet.setheading(self.player.heading())
            self.bullet.showturtle()
            self.bulletShot = True

            self.screen.update()

    def move_enemy(self):
        x = randint(-300, 300)
        y = randint(-300, 300)

        self.enemy.goto(x, y)

        self.screen.update()

    def play(self):
        if self.startTime == -1:
            self.startTime = time.time()

        if self.bulletShot:
            self.bullet.forward(1)

            x, y = self.bullet.position()

            if not(-300 <= x <= 300 and -300 <= y <= 300):
                self.bullet.hideturtle()
                self.bulletShot = False
            elif self.bullet.distance(self.enemy.pos()) < 10:
                self.bullet.hideturtle()
                self.bulletShot = False
                self.move_enemy()
                self.startTime = time.time()

            self.screen.update()

        if time.time() - self.startTime > 20:
            self.player.write('You loose!')
            self.screen.update()
        else:
            self.screen.ontimer(self.play, 10)

screen = Screen()

game = Game()

game.play()

screen.mainloop()
```

Still bit crude but should be playable.  You had a `self.scr.update()` call in your original code but without an initial call to `tracer()`, it does nothing.  Here we're using `tracer()` and `update()` to speed up and smooth out the motion by manually controlling all screen updates.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I like that it runs smoother. The first update I had is the only way I could find to brink the screen to the front (when running the code from spyder).